# Prove that a dominating set has minimum cardinality in a "unit interval graph"

Tags: graphs, sets, set-cover, check-my-answer, vertex-cover

I am given the definition of a unit interval graph, e.g. $G = (V, E)$ such that $\forall v \in V$ there is a weight $x_v \in \mathbb{R}$ and nodes $u, w$ has an edge iff $|x_u - x_w| < 1$. I am asked to find a dominating set of minimum cardinality in $G$ greedily. And prove it is a dominating set and it is also optimal.

My idea in pseudocode is as follows:

```
//For simplicity let the node weights be given in a vector x of length N
sort(x)
dom = []
group_represntative = x[0]
representative_has_moved = false 
for (i=1; i < N; i++)
  if (|group_represntative - x[i]| > 1 and !representative_has_moved)
    group_represntative = x[i-1]
    representative_has_moved = true
  if (|group_represntative - x[i]| > 1 and representative_has_moved)
    dom.push_back(group_represntative)
    // we entered the next group
    representative_has_moved = false
    group_represntative = x[i]
```

The idea of the approach is to take everytime the representative (best case the middle) of small groups, where a small group is a group within a total distance of 2 from the first element in it.

This clearly finds a dominating set.

But I remain to show that this is optimal.

My line of argument to prove it is: then for any pair of consecutive representatives, if they were wrong they must be substituted by at least 2 other elements in the dominating set. And we can apply this argument on any pair of representatives, hence this is optimal.

Does this proof suffices to show something like that?

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: No. As a rule of thumb, if a proof for the correctness of an algorithm is not **obviously** correct to you, then it is insufficient or wrong mathematically. Your line of argument can be considered as a understanding that is good enough.